# OpenMP and resource management in c++

Tags: c++, openmp

I have an resource that needs to retain its state between accesses. When parallelizing the program with OpenMP I want to make sure that each thread has its own copy and that the instances are not destroyed and created anew for each parallel region. To this end, I use a global variable that is `threadprivate`. Below, I have a simple test case that should illustrate the setting.

I have two questions:

1. Is it guaranteed that the resource (below, obj) is created only once per thread during the execution of the program?
2. When I run the example program on four threads, each thread reports "Obj created..." and "State set to..." but only thread zero reports "Obj destroyed...". What is going on here?

---

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class obj {
public:
  obj() : state(0) {
    res = new int [100];
#pragma omp critical
    {
      std::cout << "Obj created, state " << state;
#ifdef _OPENMP
      std::cout << ", thread " << omp_get_thread_num();
#endif
      std::cout << std::endl;    
    }
  }

  ~obj() {
    delete[] res;
#pragma omp critical
    {
    std::cout << "Obj destroyed, state " << state;
#ifdef _OPENMP
      std::cout << ", thread " << omp_get_thread_num();
#endif
      std::cout << std::endl;    

    }
  }

  void init(int set) {
    state = set;
#pragma omp critical
    {
      std::cout << "State set to " << state;
#ifdef _OPENMP
      std::cout << ", thread " << omp_get_thread_num();
#endif
      std::cout << std::endl;    
    }
  }

  int operator()() {
    return ++state;
  }

private:
  int state;
  int* res;
};

extern obj obj1;
#pragma omp threadprivate(obj1)
obj obj1;

void init() {
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel
  {
  obj1.init(100 * omp_get_thread_num());
  }
#else
  obj1.init(100);
#endif  
}

void work() {
  std::cout << "Computing" << std::endl;

  int constexpr length = 20;
  std::vector<int> vec(length);

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
    vec[idx] = obj1();
  }

  std::cout.fill('0');

  for (auto const & e: vec) {
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << e << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  init();
  work();
  work();
  work();
}
```

Comment: well, I would guess that when obj1 go out of scope, (at the end of main I guess as it's global variables), the other threads are already dead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

threadprivate works correctly under following conditions

- `#pragma omp threadprivate` is present *after* **each** declaration of the variable;
- dynamic threads must be turned off (default is implementation-defined) with `omp_set_dynamic(false)`.

See example [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#THREADPRIVATE).

I wouldn't rely on destructors being called at all.  OpenMP leaves a lot of it unspecified and compiler may optimize it out.

Here's a excerpt from OpenMP Spec (v4.0 p.12.14.2)

> The storage of all copies of a threadprivate variable is freed according to how static variables are handled in the base language, but at an unspecified point in the program.

and

> The order in which any destructors for different threadprivate C++ variables of class type are called is unspecified.

More info on `threadprivate`
(v4.0 p2.4.12)

> Each copy of a `threadprivate` variable is initialized once, in the manner specified by the program, but at an unspecified point in the program prior to the first reference to that copy. The storage of all copies of a `threadprivate` variable is freed according to how static variables are handled in the base language, but at an unspecified point in the program.
>
> A program in which a thread references another thread’s copy of a `threadprivate` variable is non-conforming.
>
> The content of a `threadprivate` variable can change across a task scheduling point if the executing thread switches to another task that modifies the variable. For more details on task scheduling, see Section 1.3 on page 14 and Section 2.11 on page 113.
>
> In `parallel` regions, references by the master thread will be to the copy of the variable in the thread that encountered the `parallel` region.
>
> During a sequential part references will be to the initial thread’s copy of the variable. The values of data in the initial thread’s copy of a `threadprivate` variable are guaranteed to persist between any two consecutive references to the variable in the program.
>
> The values of data in the `threadprivate` variables of non-initial threads are guaranteed to persist between two consecutive active `parallel` regions only if all the following conditions hold:
>
> - Neither `parallel` region is nested inside another explicit `parallel` region.
> - The number of threads used to execute both `parallel` regions is the same.
> - The thread affinity policies used to execute both `parallel` regions are the same.
> - The value of the *dyn-var* internal control variable in the enclosing task region is *false* at entry to both `parallel` regions.
>
> If these conditions all hold, and if a `threadprivate` variable is referenced in both regions, then threads with the same thread number in their respective regions will reference the same copy of that variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know why the output from the other destructors does not get printed?

Comment: OpenMP creates new variables in the thread scope (for example, using `thread_local`) for each thread.  As you keep the number of threads constant, it does not terminate threads.  Thus these variables never go out of scope and destructors are not called.  Try calling `omp_set_num_threads(2)` and you will probably see extra destructors called.

Comment: I edited the answer to cite a couple of unspecified behaviors on destructing from OpenMP spec.